# How to reset material properties to default values after game shutdown?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader-graph

I created a color property in the shader graph and set the color through the unity inspector. Then I changed it with the code:

```
image.material.SetColor("_MainColor", colorNew);
```

However, I noticed that after the game ends, the material color remains the one I set in the code. It does not revert to the default value, like object coordinates for example.

What am I understanding wrong? How to return the values?

I expected the property values to be returned to default after restarting the game

Comment: In that case can you not simply go through `image.color =` ...?

Comment: @derHugo , Yes, that's the easiest solution, thank you

Comment: Does it stay in the final build? Not in the ide?

Comment: @BugFinder no .. but it screws up your assets so in the build it would start wrong

Comment: @derHugo thats always been my annoyance with SOs too. Too much remembered while not running in the ide these days